# Cointegration: Long vs Short Run

Tags: time-series, cointegration, ecm

I am running an ECM model that has one cointegrating vector but two stochastic trends within the cointegration vector ex.(1, -1, 1). Can I use the cointegration vector inside an error correction model that does not contain one of the regressors that was used for the cointegration vector?

Example, $x_{2,t}$ is used in first-step of approximating the cointegrating vector but not used in the error correction model:
$$
y_{t} =  \alpha +   \gamma_1 x_{1,t} + \gamma_2 x_{2,t} +  u_{t} 
$$

After, the above is estimated it is added as the error correction in the below ECM:

$$
\Delta y_{t} = c + \beta_{1}\Delta y_{t-1} + \beta_{2}\Delta x_{1,t-1}  + \delta( {y}_{t-1} -  \widehat{a} - \widehat{\gamma_1}x_{1,t-1} - \widehat{\gamma_2}x_{2,t-1}) + v_{t}
$$

Comment: But $x_{2,t-1}$ **is** used in the ECM equation for $\Delta y_t$.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if the x2 can be included and used in the cointegrating vector but not in the first-differenced part of the ECM. I would assume that this means it significantly explains long-run dynamics but not short-run dynamics (as it was very insignificant in the first-differenced part).

Comment: Yes, there is no contradiction in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u_t$ in the first equation is I(0) so that you have cointegration between $y$, $x_1$ and $x_2$, then the second equation is fine*. There can be processes where lags of some variables are on the right hand side; in this case the lag of $\Delta x_{2,t}$ is not included in the model for $\Delta y_t$. This is nothing contradictory or wrong by itself.

*You need an error term in the last equation, though.

Comment: Yes, in the first equation y, x1 and x2 are I(1) processes and their residual u is I(0). Also, added the error term to the ECM.